# Java Checking folder name for number with 14 digits

Tags: java, regex, directory, digits

i am trying to make my java program search in a directory for any other folders that contains the word "natives". I have all that working. But to insure more security i would also like it to check for numbers seeing the actual folder is called "1.7.4-natives-16411115736623".

All in all i want my java program to check if a directory with "natives" in the name. if so, check if the folder name contains a "-16411115736623" after the word natives. Keep in mind these numbers are random, but are always 14 digits.

Here is my current code:

'File folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"/Library/Application Support/minecraft/versions/");

File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

outerloop:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                    String filePathString = (System.getProperty("user.home")+"/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/versions/"+listOfFiles[i].getName()+"/");
                    File folder2 = new File(filePathString);
                    File[] listOfFiles2 = folder2.listFiles();
                    for (int f = 0; f < listOfFiles2.length; f++){
                        if(listOfFiles2[f].getName().contains("natives")) {
                            mcRunning = true;
                            System.out.println(listOfFiles2[f]);
                            System.out.println("Folder Exists");
                            Utils.verifyJars(filePathString);
                        }else{
                            System.out.println(listOfFiles2[f]);
                            System.out.println("Folder does Exist");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }'
```

Comment: Glad to hear it works, thanks. :) Hey btw, I notice you haven't yet voted on StackOverflow. For any of the answers you find helpful, please consider voting up as this is how the reputation system works. Of course no obligation to do so. Thanks for listening to my 10-second SO rep tutorial. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Do both at the same time**

There is no need for a second check. Regex allows you to check **both** that the folder names contains `natives`, and that `natives` is followed by a dash and 14 digits, in a single pass.

Use this regex: `natives-\d{14}`

Or, if the 14 digits must terminate the folder name, use `natives-\d{14}$` (otherwise you could match `some-natives-0123456789012311111 and my dog`)

To do this in your code, where you have `if(listOfFiles2[f].getName().contains("natives"))`, you can use this instead:

```
// before the outer for loop
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("natives-\\d{14}$");

// later
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(listOfFiles2[f].getName());
if(regexMatcher.find()) {... success ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

for your inner loop use the regex method `String.matches`

the regex is rather simple, since you know it will be 14 digits

```
if(name.matches("[0-9]{14}")){
...
}
```